# AJAX form sends but PHP script not functioning

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have got this form that loops through some products in my database:

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE top = 'yes' and everything = 'true'"; 
    $featured = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
?>

<?php while ($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($featured)): ?>

<form class="myform" method="POST" class="ajax">
    <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<?=$product['id'];?>">

    <input type="hidden" name="salec" value="<?=$product['sale'];?>">

    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="<?=$product['title'];?>">

    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" class="hidden_price" value="<?=$product['price'];?>">

    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_list_price" class="hidden_list_price" value="<?=$product['list_price'];?>">

    <input type="hidden" name="collect" class="collect" value="<?=$product['collection'];?>">

    <input type="hidden" name="himg" class="himg" value="<?=$product['image'];?>">

    <select name="quantity" class="quantity">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>

    <input type="submit" class="button" name="cartbtn" value="Quick Add-to-Cart">

</form>

<?php endwhile ?>
```

There is nothing wrong in terms of the form.  I have added it for clarity. 
Here is the AJAX code that submits the form data to a separate PHP script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('.myform').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '../PHP_Scripts/quick_cart.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function () {
          alert('form was submitted');
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Ok so, its the `PHP_Scripts/quick_cart.php` that is not doing what I want it to, just a simple echo:

```
<?php
     if (isset($_POST['cartbtn'])) {
         echo "hello";
     }
?>
```

It is just a test to see if it actually works or not. The alert triggers fine but the echo is not showing up.

Comment: The reason why it's having issues is because you have 2 classes in your `form` tag. `class="myform" method="POST" class="ajax"`

Comment: Replace `<form class="myform" method="POST" class="ajax">` with `<form class="myform ajax" method="POST">`

Comment: FYI, you are missing a `</select>`.  `endwhile` is missing a `;`.

Comment: @MA Ive ammended these errors, thankyou for pointing them out to me. However, it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: you haven't provided enough information here.  look at the console. post errors, http response code. what does $_POST contain? where are you expecting to see "hello" given that you aren't capturing the ajax response? are php short tags enabled?

Comment: @billynoah HI, php short tags are enabled, there are no errors in the console, response code is 200. I haven't specified where I want the text to go, the screen is near enough blank so I should see it if it appeared. any ideas?

Comment: you aren't getting the ajax response anywhere... `success: function (response) {`

Comment: @billynoah yes, i am.

Comment: ok, i don't see it in the code you posted. where?

Comment: You forgot to put closing tag for the SELECT tag. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are **trying to validate a post submit button passed by serialized form**.

**Ajax post serialize() does not include button name and value**.They aren't considered to be "successful controls". This is because the serialize() method has no way of knowing what button was clicked.

**SOLUTION #1:** Try to replace your `PHP_Scripts/quick_cart.php` with

```
if (!empty($_POST)){
 echo "hello";
}
```

This is to check in general if there is a `post` action.

**SOLUTION #2:**
If you still want to validate the button, you should concatenate this in your serialized data before passing to ajax.

Edit your javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('.myform').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var myform=$('.myform').serialize();
    var curSubmit = $("input[type=submit]",this);

    var myform = myform
    + '&' 
    + encodeURI(curSubmit.attr('name'))
    + '='
    + encodeURI(curSubmit.attr('value'))
;
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '../PHP_Scripts/quick_cart.php',
        data: myform,
        success: function () {
          alert('form was submitted');
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. @K.Doe should also note that his loop through products will output multiple <forms>, which means the jQuery selector he's using for serialize may not select the correct product.